# adding my own control to the toolbox

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, custom-controls, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Does anyone know why I can't add a subclass that inherits a control from AjaxControlToolKit to the ToolKit? I explicitly implemented IComponent which I didn't really have to since the IControl in the parent implements IComponent already. I'll compile the code, and try to add the DLL but I get the "doesn't contain any controls" error. I know this is a very specific error so there wasn't much help elsewhere.

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Component"),
ToolboxData("<{0}:TabPanelWithDataBinding runat=server></{0}:TabPanelWithDataBinding>")]
public class TabPanelWithDataBinding : TabPanel, IComponent, IDisposable
{
//all the meat stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your base class "`TabPanel`" has an attribute `[ToolboxItem(false)]`. Which does filter the control from the assembly. You can try adding this attribute to your control with `true` as argument.